# React Unit Testing Jest using Typescript problem with mount()

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, jestjs, enzyme

I have this simple app / components

```
import GraphicCanvas from './Graphing/GraphCanvas';
import { drawCircle } from './Graphing/DrawCircle';
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
     < GraphicCanvas  draw={drawCircle} />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

---

```
    import React, { FC, useRef, useEffect } from "react";
    
    export interface IGraphicCanvas{
        draw : Function;
    }
    
    const GraphicCanvas : FC<IGraphicCanvas> = (props) : JSX.Element => {
        const canvasRef = useRef<HTMLCanvasElement>(null)
    
        useEffect(() => {
            if (canvasRef.current) {
                const canvas = canvasRef.current
                const context = canvas?.getContext('2d')
                props.draw(context)
            }
        }, [props.draw])
    return <canvas ref={canvasRef} />

}

export default GraphicCanvas ;
```

---

```
export const drawCircle = (ctx : CanvasRenderingContext2D | null ) : void => {
    ctx!.fillStyle = '#000000'
    ctx?.beginPath()
    ctx?.arc(50, 100, 20, 0, 2 * Math.PI)
    ctx?.fill()
}
```

It works and renders a small black dot .

My problem is trying to write a unit test with Enzyme and Jest, mount() errors.

Below is my test, which is pretty self explanatory in what it's trying to test.

```
import React from 'react'
import { configure, shallow, mount } from "enzyme";
import Adapter from "enzyme-adapter-react-16";

import GraphicCanvas, { IGraphicCanvas } from "./GraphCanvas";
import  { drawCircle }  from "./DrawCircle"

configure({ adapter: new Adapter() });

describe("GraphCanvas ", () => {
  
  let props: IGraphicCanvas;
  let useEffect: { getMockImplementation: (arg0: (ctx: CanvasRenderingContext2D | null) => void) => void; }
  
  const mockUseEffect = () => {
    useEffect.getMockImplementation( drawCircle );
  };

  beforeEach(() => {
    props = { draw: jest.fn().getMockImplementation }; 
  });

  //shallow method renders only a single component, without child components.
  it("renders without crashing", () => {
    shallow(<GraphicCanvas draw={drawCircle} />);
  });

  it("calls function drawCircle passed in props as draw", () => {
    //mockUseEffect();
    //mount(<GraphicCanvas draw={drawCircle} />);
    mount(<GraphicCanvas {...props} />);
    expect(props.draw).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });

});
```

When I run my test I get the following error

```
  ● GraphCanvas  › calls function drawCircle passed in props as draw

    TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'child')

      29 |     //mockUseEffect();
      30 |     //mount(<GraphicCanvas draw={drawCircle} />);
    > 31 |     mount(<GraphicCanvas {...props} />);
         |     ^
      32 |     expect(props.draw).toHaveBeenCalled();
      33 |   });
      34 |
```

If I uncomment line 30 I get the same error

If I uncomment line 29 I get

```
 ● GraphCanvas  › calls function drawCircle passed in props as draw

    TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getMockImplementation')

      14 |   
      15 |   const mockUseEffect = () => {
    > 16 |     useEffect.getMockImplementation( drawCircle );
         |               ^
      17 |   };
```

Obviously I'm doing something very wrong with line 29

But I can't understand with both line 30 and 31 fail

All I'm trying to do is test that the function drawCircle which is passed in as a prop "draw" to GraphicCanvas is called

```
 expect(props.draw).toHaveBeenCalled()
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to mock `useEffect()` hook. Just use the original version, because we want the component to behave correctly, not the test implementation details, which can make the test vulnerable, and a small change in the implementation details can cause the test case to fail. Incorrect mock also destroys the behavior of `useEffect`, this will cause the test case to pass, but the code is wrong at runtime.

We only care about the behavior and functionality of the component, not the implementation details.

`GraphqCanvas.tsx`:

```
import React, { FC, useRef, useEffect } from 'react';

export interface IGraphicCanvas {
  draw: Function;
}

const GraphicCanvas: FC<IGraphicCanvas> = (props): JSX.Element => {
  const canvasRef = useRef<HTMLCanvasElement>(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (canvasRef.current) {
      const canvas = canvasRef.current;
      const context = canvas?.getContext('2d');
      props.draw(context);
    }
  }, [props.draw]);
  return <canvas ref={canvasRef} />;
};

export default GraphicCanvas;
```

`GraphicCanvas.test.tsx`:

```
import GraphicCanvas, { IGraphicCanvas } from './GraphCanvas';
import { configure, shallow, mount } from 'enzyme';
import Adapter from 'enzyme-adapter-react-16';
import React from 'react';
configure({ adapter: new Adapter() });

describe('GraphicCanvas', () => {
  let props: IGraphicCanvas;
  beforeEach(() => {
    props = { draw: jest.fn() };
  });
  it('calls function drawCircle passed in props as draw', () => {
    HTMLCanvasElement.prototype.getContext = jest.fn();
    mount(<GraphicCanvas {...props} />);
    expect(props.draw).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
});
```

test result:

```
 PASS  examples/69780222/GraphCanvas.test.tsx (10.389 s)
  GraphicCanvas
    ✓ calls function drawCircle passed in props as draw (35 ms)

-----------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
File             | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s 
-----------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
All files        |     100 |    66.67 |     100 |     100 |                   
 GraphCanvas.tsx |     100 |    66.67 |     100 |     100 | 11-13             
-----------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        11.08 s
Ran all test suites related to changed files.
```

package versions:

```json
"enzyme": "^3.11.0",
"enzyme-adapter-react-16": "^1.15.5",
"jest": "^26.6.3",
"react": "^16.14.0",
```

Comment: Just ran your test and it fails to mount. I'm using the latest version of React,Jest and Enzyme in my package  Json
  ● GraphicCanvas › calls function drawCircle passed in props as draw

    TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'child')

      12 |   it('calls function drawCircle passed in props as draw', () => {
      13 |     HTMLCanvasElement.prototype.getContext = jest.fn();
    > 14 |     mount(<GraphicCanvas {...props} />);
         |     ^
      15 |     expect(props.draw).toHaveBeenCalled();
      16 |   });
      17 | });

Answer (score 0):

It appears that Enzyme doesn't yet support React version 17, so mount fails.
There is an unofficial adaptor for v17 search for @wojtekmaj/enzyme-adapter-react-17.

Below is my simple working test

```
import GraphicCanvas, { IGraphicCanvas } from './GraphCanvas';
import { configure, mount } from "enzyme";
import Adapter from '@wojtekmaj/enzyme-adapter-react-17'

configure({ adapter: new Adapter() });

describe('GraphicCanvas', () => {
  let props: IGraphicCanvas;
  beforeEach(() => {
    props = { draw: jest.fn() };
  });
  it('calls function drawCircle passed in props as draw', () => {
      HTMLCanvasElement.prototype.getContext = jest.fn();
      mount(<GraphicCanvas {...props} />);
      expect(props.draw).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
});
```